# How do I write an html form of variable length to a plain text file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am somewhat new to the world of website design. I have an HTML form that consists of a dropdown box and an input box. I also have a button that creates move dropdown boxes and input boxes. There is not a limit on how many the user can create.

Once the user has put all of their desired input in, I want to take the entire form and write it to a plain text file (this will be used in a Python script). How can I do this without using a php form? Any input would be helpful. Thanks!

HTML form:

```
    <form>
    <table id = "actions_table" style="position: absolute; left: 486px; top: 25px">
        <tr>
            <td><select name = "action" id = "action" style="width: 108px;">
                <option value = "Click_button">Click Button</option>
                <option value = "Input_search">Input Search</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><input type = "text" style="width:100px" name = "input_text"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type = "submit" value="Add to Scrape" style="position: absolute; left: 720px; top: 150px; width:100px">
    </form>
```

Add to form button:

```
<button type = "button" onclick="addAction()" style="position:absolute; left: 1050px; top: 125px;">Add Action</button>
```

Action behind Add to form button:

```
        <script>
            function addAction(){
                //Get table
                var action_table = document.getElementById("actions_table");

                //Add selection box
                var new_input_option = document.createElement("select");
                new_input_option.style.width = "108px";

                //Add option for click button
                var click_opt = document.createElement("option")
                click_opt.text = "Click Button"

                //Add option for input search
                var input_opt = document.createElement("option")
                input_opt.text = "Input Search"

                //add options
                new_input_option.add(click_opt)
                new_input_option.add(input_opt)

                //Create new input box
                var input_box = document.createElement("input")
                input_box.style.width = "100px"
                //Insert new row below last one
                let newRow = action_table.insertRow(-1)
                let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0)
                let newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1)

                //Add stuff
                newCell.appendChild(new_input_option);
                newCell2.appendChild(input_box);
            }
        </script>
```

I have found ways to write designated form fields by the name of the field, but I just have not been able to simply get all elements from the form and write them to a plain text file. Thanks again for any input!

Comment: Have you tried using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)? Can you update your code to show what you've tried to meet this requirement, along with a succinct explanation of where in that attempt you're getting stuck? [ask]

Comment: Write it to a plain text file WHERE? The user's machine, or the server? JS cannot write it to the server - it would have to POST it, or send a request somewhere. Might as well just post the form at that point.

Comment: I am trying to write it to a plain text file on the users machine. None of this application is going on a server. Overall, I just need to get the current state of the form at any given point and write its contents to a plain text file on the users machine.

Comment: Between the link @esqew posted to write the file, and this one for how to get the name/value pairs, that should get you started [Serialize form data into an object in vanilla JS](https://barker.codes/blog/serialize-form-data-into-an-object-in-vanilla-js)